# Playing audio from url in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to play audio from the url in kotlin in Android Studio but I am getting error in **setDataSource()** when am putting url in it.

```
    val mP = MediaPlayer()
    val url_play_btn: Button = findViewById(R.id.url_play_btn)

    url_play_btn.setOnClickListener{

        var url : String = "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3"

        mP.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

            try{
                mP.setDataSource(url)
                mP.prepare()
                mP.start()
            }
            catch(e:Exception){
                Log.i("Error","Couldn't Play the Audio")
                Toast.makeText(this,"$e",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

    }
```

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the full message. If you do not understand the message, post the full message (including any stack trace) as an edit to your question.

Comment: What error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: i got an error io.IOException: setDataSource failed